# JavaFX: JNLP file error

Tags: javafx, java-web-start, jnlp, javafx-1

I'm getting the following error when I upload a JavaFX app to a website, but I don't get it locally.

I'm presuming that I'm missing something like the 'codebase' tag, but I'm not sure where it goes, can anyone help me out please?

Java Console error:

```
exception: JNLP file error: iShout_Foxpro_browser.jnlp. 
Please make sure the file exists and check if "codebase" and "href" in the JNLP
   file are correct..
java.io.FileNotFoundException: JNLP file error: iShout_Foxpro_browser.jnlp. 
Please make sure the file exists and check if "codebase" and "href" in the JNLP 
  file are correct.
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JNLP file error:     
  iShout_Foxpro_browser.jnlp.     
Please make sure the file exists and check if "codebase" and "href" in the 
  JNLP file are correct.
```

HTML file source...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>app_one</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://dl.javafx.com/1.3/dtfx.js"></script>
<script>
javafx(
    {
          archive: "app_one.jar",
          draggable: true,
          width: 480,
          height: 320,
          code: "app.Main",
          name: "app_one"
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the full path to the jar into the 'archive' property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew Hegarty, seems you are correct, the "archieve" property was not pointing to the correct location when it had been uploaded to the server.

If you put an answer down, I'll tick it as the correct answer.

Thanks
Jeff Porter